# MacBook Pro with Touch ID sometimes unlocks without any authentication

Tags: macbook-pro, security, macos, unlock, touch-id

My MacBook Pro with TouchBar is set up to use Touch ID, requires authentication after sleeping, has File Vault turned on… the complete works. Yet twice now I have noticed that it seemed to unlock after sleep without any input. It neither asked for the password nor did it require me to touch the Touch ID sensor. It only seems to happen at work, not at home. I did not have anything plugged in at the time; I opened the lid and was just about to plug in an external keyboard and monitor when it already presented the unlocked desktop. I'm pretty sure it was asleep before, as this was the first thing I did in the morning after taking it out of its bag.

Very strange. Any ideas what that is?

Here's an excerpt of system.log:

```
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro syslogd[35]: ASL Sender Statistics
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro logd[52]: _handle_cache_delete_with_urgency(0x7f8f90064190, 3, 0)
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro logd[52]: _volume_contains_cached_data(is /private/var/db/diagnostics/ in /) - YES
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro logd[52]: 150114280 bytes of purgeable space from log files
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro logd[52]: _purge_uuidtext only runs at urgency 0 (3)
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro logd[52]: 0 bytes of purgeable space from uuidtext files
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.138 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayUsbRecvComplete] failed 0xe00002ed
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.142 [DFR] [deviceTerminate] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.142 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.142 [DFR] [___DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved_block_invoke] calling client detach callback
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.142 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayClose] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.176 [DFR] [deviceMatch] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.176 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceAdded] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.178 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayUsbStart] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.178 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] 
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.179 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] sending GetInfo
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.180 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayHandleVendorPacket] kDFRDisplayCommandGetInfo ready: 0
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.180 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayHandleVendorPacket] calling client attach callback
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911427.180 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayHandleVendorPacket] kDFRDisplayCommandGetInfo ready: 1
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.23557): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/RootDebuggingXPCService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Dec 27 08:36:45 Davids-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.23557): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/DFRSupportKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Dec 27 08:36:47 Davids-MacBook-Pro diagnosticd[225]: Streaming server Reconnected
Dec 27 08:36:47 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 27 08:36:47 Davids-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome[6971]: objc[6971]: __weak variable at 0x618000a5fa50 holds 0x2121212121212121 instead of 0x618000e2d280. This is probably incorrect use of objc_storeWeak() and objc_loadWeak(). Break on objc_weak_error to debug.
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.078 [DFR] ERR [_DFRDisplayUsbRecvComplete] failed 0xe00002eb
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.115 [DFR] [deviceTerminate] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.115 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.116 [DFR] [___DFRDisplayDeviceRemoved_block_invoke] calling client detach callback
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.116 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayClose] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.513 [DFR] [deviceMatch] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.514 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayDeviceAdded] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.514 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayUsbStart] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.515 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] 
Dec 27 08:45:43 Davids-MacBook-Pro WindowServer[143]: 911965.515 [DFR] [_DFRDisplayOpen] sending GetInfo
...
```

I looks like a very similar pattern repeats every ~15 minutes (which is probably normal for dark-wake I'd assume). At 8:36 there the laptop was in its bag, at 8:45 was a legitimate wakeup event. Not sure if this adds any additional clues…

Comment: Do you wear an Apple Watch? Also, what is the lock interval (System Settings → Security & Privacy)?

Comment: No; and "5 seconds after sleep or screen saver begins."

Comment: I have a suspicion an app or agent/daemon may be interrupting sleep. You can test this by closing them all and seeing if it occurs again. Alternatively, the App Nap column in the Energy tab of Activity Monitor can give some indication.

Comment: But even if that was the case, that shouldn't cause it to unlock‽ That would mean it was unlocked and not asleep for about 10 hours in its bag…

Comment: It just happened again right now. The laptop was in the bag over night (10+ hours), took a few seconds to wake up (no instant-on screen, looks like it was really sleeping), and battery is at 98% (doesn't look like it had insomnia all night).

Comment: I just chatted with Apple, and they pretty much came to the same conclusion. It's apparently not impossible that the laptop didn't go to sleep at all (which makes the battery consumption impressive). I'll see if I can narrow that down to some specific app causing issues.

Comment: The new MBP's are known (or notorious, depending on your POV) for having wildly variable autonomy times. It's extremely economic when it's idle. But it should still lock & sleep. Please report back if you find the cause. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be that the laptop never went to sleep in the first place, and hence never locked either. Amazingly it stayed on over night (with disabled display I assume) and didn't consume more than ~2% battery.

The culprit may or may not have been the Steam client; I don't have any particular evidence for it, but it's been misbehaving a lot on Sierra and seems like a likely candidate which prevented sleep.

Comment: But doesn't macOS lock whenever the screen is disabled, not just when it goes to sleep?

Comment: You'd think so, right? Apparently that's not necessarily the case. Or the screen actually did stay on, I have no idea. The thing that's somewhat reassuring is that it doesn't unlock by itself…

Comment: Good point—since the glowing Apple logo has been removed, we have no way of knowing if the screen stays on or not.  In theory it should always go off if the lid is closed, but of course that can be messed with.